# match with month and year in sql database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am currently using code below to get results. but it some times give wrong result because it tries to match with today's date. while i want that it should try to match only current month and year only. it should not match the current day(date).

```
$this->db->select('*')
               ->where('u_id',$user)
               ->where('month','CURDATE()',FALSE)
               ->from('basepointsbymonth');
               $que=$this->db->get();
```

please provide any solution.

Comment: what you try so far ?? insert your code here

Comment: Please tell me your date column uses a `DATE` datatype and you've just written it incorrectly in the question.... please.

Comment: solution already posted by several users..google it first...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the most recent date in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624240/how-can-i-get-the-most-recent-date-in-sql)

Comment: datatype is date. and i have checked on google already and the results were nonsatisfactory

Comment: In what sense were the googled solutions unsatisfactory?

Comment: i want to update the data not select

Comment: @Strawberry i changed the topic please answer this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

`where MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE())  AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE())`

Comment: Don't forget to replace the date with the name of the date column you want to match

Comment: yeah already noticed that. but bro you saved my day today. thank you very much. it worked siraa